# Passing data between two unrelated React apps

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an HTML page that is including two separate webpack-generated React bundles, each with its own `index.js` entry file that just does a `RenderDOM.render()` of its respective component to its respective `<div>`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="stylesheets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="retrieveBtn"
            style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; width: 10%">
            Recuperar Presupuesto
        </div>
        <div id="lightbox-portal"
            style="display: none; border: 1px solid grey">
            <div id="react-retrieve"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section class="tariff">
        <div id="react-main" class="tariff__content fadeIn js-animated"></div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="/eco/econonrps_vflx/build/static/js/main_bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/eco/retrieve_vflx/build/static/js/retrieve_bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When `<div id="uxvida-retrieve"></div>` is displayed and we enter data in it, we receive an AJAX response with assorted data.

We tried this: On page load each component gets rendered, we receive data and from component attached to `id="react-retrieve"` we do another `ReactDOM.render()` to `id="react-main"`.

That generates a lot of coupling and the constructors get called again, and I don't want that.

In short, how do I pass that data to the other React Component/App without calling again `ReactDOM.render()`?

Comment: I don't know much about react but in the end it's just javascript. Can't you make a globally accessible "interface" on one or both of  your "components"? In other words can you not declare a method on one of your react components that can be called from the global scope by the other react component?

Comment: have you considered using localstorage? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Oh, I didn't consider localStorage at all! It might be just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think localStorage is the answer. I reached here with the exact same question of sharing data while using a micro-frontend architecture.
I am using localstorage currently and that seems to be perfect solution providing availability of data without race conditions.

Things to consider:
1. localStorage data is always stored as string.
2. While saving structured JSON object, stringify and after retrieval parse.
3. It might become a bad choice while trying to save dynamic data involving scripts, etc that cannot be easily stringified.
4. Saving it in a global variable and delaying in react app initialization till the variable is available for the app to consume can be a good choice here.
    This can be done via a recursive function call or timeout while retrieving the data from global var.

```
let data = false; // tmp global var consisting data.
const getData = ()=>{
  if(!data){
    setTimeout(()=>{getData()},100)  // timeout simply to be considerate
  }
}
```

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old question, but I just had the same problem. I have 2 components embedded in one page (separate react apps). One of the components send Ajax request, and the second one must do sth after the first one get the response.

I solved the problem with CustomEvents https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events. Simply after the first component fetch the results, it sends the custom event that the other component is listning to.

I'm not a frontend developer, so not sure if it is the correct way to handle the issue but it seems a good solution to me.

Answer (score -4):

If I got you right, you have 2 seperated react appliadtions that renders to the same page. If so, why you can't manage only one app to do so ?

Anyway, I would suggest to merge the 2 apps, or to change server Api call: server can return only the delta data, I mean only the difference from last call from same user/token.

Comment: there can be various reusable micro apps on single web page with independent functionalities. Thus, creating a micro-frontend architecture.